# Is it possible to implement a value change in a textbox depending on the change of values in two comboboxes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I need advice on Windows Forms. I need to make the textbox change the value depending on which values I choose in the two comboboxes.

For example. I have a combobox with a choice of machines(1,2,3,4 etc.) and a combobox with a choice of products(a,b,c,d etc.). I need a textbox with the number of products produced(100,200,300,400 etc.) to change based on the choice of two values of comboboxes. This value of the textbox should depend on the machine and the product values.
The problem is that I don't know how to solve the fact that product "a" can be combined with different machines, and these are different textbox values.

I managed to make the value in the textbox change when I selected one combobox. But there are no ideas at all to link one textbox and two comboboxes.
Thank you!

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant XML and sql-server tags. Please [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. Add 'OnChange' Event handlers to the two combos that execute a bit of code to set text box...

Comment: Add an event to the `SelectedIndexChanged` for both comboboxes. Implement whatever update logic you want in this event handler to update the textbox.

Comment: Or you can create a model class which exposes machines and products as get-set-properties and the text as calculated get property, implement INotifyPropertyChanged and use binding with this class as object datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No exactly know what your issue is.Here is a full code example of how to link two comboboxes to update a textbox value in Windows Forms.You can separate the `SelectedIndexChanged` event based on what you want.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> machineProductValues;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        machineProductValues = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>()
        {
            {new Tuple<string, string>("Machine 1", "Product A"), 100},
            {new Tuple<string, string>("Machine 1", "Product B"), 200},
            {new Tuple<string, string>("Machine 2", "Product A"), 300},
            {new Tuple<string, string>("Machine 2", "Product B"), 400}
        };

        // Populate comboboxes 
        machineCombo.Items.Add("Machine 1");
        machineCombo.Items.Add("Machine 2");

        productCombo.Items.Add("Product A");
        productCombo.Items.Add("Product B");

        // Subscribe to events
        machineCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += Combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
        productCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += Combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void Combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateOutputValue();
    }

    private void UpdateOutputValue()
    {
        string machine = machineCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string product = productCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Tuple<string, string> key = new Tuple<string, string>(machine, product);

        if (machineProductValues.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            outputTextBox.Text = machineProductValues[key].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the new [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) to simplify your code. I.e, `Dictionary<(string, string), int>` and initialize with `{("Machine 1", "Product A"), 100}`. See also: [C# 7.0: Tuples Explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained).

Comment: This should work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this example:

```cs
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxMachines.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            comboBoxProducts.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var machine = comboBoxMachines.SelectedText;
            var product = comboBoxProducts.SelectedText;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machine) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
            {
                return;
            }

            this.textBoxProduced.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                textBoxProduced.Text = GetProductCountForMachine(machine, product).ToString();
            });
        }

        private int GetProductCountForMachine(string machine, string product)
        {
            // enter your logic here and return the count
            return 0;
        }
    }
```